# The command "jupyter lab" does not work as the file does not exist

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I installed Jupyter Lab but cannot launch it (`jupyter lab`) due to the error: *Error executing Jupyter command 'lab': [Errno 2] No such file or directory*.

However, it is installed, and is show as one of available subcommands (via `jupyter lab`):

> Available subcommands: bundlerextension console kernelspec lab labextension
>   labhub migrate nbconvert nbextension notebook qtconsole run serverextension
>   troubleshoot trust

Why does it not work and is there something I'm missing here? `jupyter notebook` works without any problems. I also added `jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab --sys-prefix` according to [the documentation](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) on Github, FYI.

My working environment:

```
jupyter notebook --version # 5.0.0
jupyter version # 4.3.0
```

Comment: This is most likely trivial, but I have the notebook version of 5.6.0, and jupyter version of 4.4.0, and it works fine for me. Maybe try upgrading the software itself.

Answer (score 6):

@Blazard open the .profile in your home using VIM add the following path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<user-name>/.local/bin
```

save it

```
$ source ~/.profile (Dont forget to do this)
```

Comment: Thanks anish kumar! Can you explain more of the details?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Installing it over PyCharm IDE solved the problem for me. I am using Windows as an OS. Installing packages over PyCharm works in general better for me than over Windows cmd.

Answer (score 0):

@Blaszard could you try the following

```
/home/<your-user-name>/.local/bin/jupyter-lab
```

[SOURCE](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3921#issuecomment-416798604)

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you would have to add `/home/<your-user-name>/.local/bin` to your `PATH` variable. However, you should probably just try it manually first and see if that even works at all.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution I found for my mac powerbook is:

go to a working directory in the terminal and then type jupyter lab.

IT WORKS,

Answer (score 0):

We need to find `jupyter-lab` command. In my case on a mac it is in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/`.

I'm using `macports` so my binaries are in `/opt/local/bin`. It's on my path:

```
> echo $PATH
.../opt/local/bin...
```

I have to create a symbolic link in this directory:

```
ln -s /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/jupyter-lab jupyter-lab
```